# How can I filter attribute from json file using nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

So I'm working with a batch JSON file with the following value :

```json
[
  {
    "eventType": "UPDATE",
    "eventTime": "2021-12-14T12:34:56.789012Z",
    "country": "ES",
    "resourceType": "Party"
  },
  {
    "eventType": "UPDATE",
    "eventTime": "2021-12-14T12:34:56.789012Z",
    "country": "ES",
    "resourceType": "Party"
  },
  {
    "eventType": "UPDATE",
    "eventTime": "2021-12-14T12:34:56.789012Z",
    "country": "FR",
    "resourceType": "Party"
  },
  {
    "eventType": "UPDATE",
    "eventTime": "2021-12-14T12:34:56.789012Z",
    "country": "FR",
    "resourceType": "Party"
  }
]
```

I'm able to extract attributes from JSON by using **`EvaluateJsonPath`** processor.

**`UpdateAttribute`** is the processor where i want to extract the attributes. Please find below snapshot of **`UpdateAttribute`** processor when value of ***`"country="ES"`***

I want get json file like this:

```json
[
  {
    "eventType": "UPDATE",
    "eventTime": "2021-12-14T12:34:56.789012Z",
    "country": "ES",
    "resourceType": "Party"
  },
  {
    "eventType": "UPDATE",
    "eventTime": "2021-12-14T12:34:56.789012Z",
    "country": "ES",
    "resourceType": "Party"
  }
]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `QueryRecord` [processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.20.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/additionalDetails.html):

- `Record Reader`: `JsonTreeReader`
- `Record Writer`: `JsonRecordSetWriter`
- `filter` (dynamic property): `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE country='ES'`

Input (JSON):

```json
[
  {
    "eventType": "UPDATE",
    "eventTime": "2021-12-14T12:34:56.789012Z",
    "country": "ES",
    "resourceType": "Party"
  },
  {
    "eventType": "UPDATE",
    "eventTime": "2021-12-14T12:34:56.789012Z",
    "country": "ES",
    "resourceType": "Party"
  },
  {
    "eventType": "UPDATE",
    "eventTime": "2021-12-14T12:34:56.789012Z",
    "country": "FR",
    "resourceType": "Party"
  },
  {
    "eventType": "UPDATE",
    "eventTime": "2021-12-14T12:34:56.789012Z",
    "country": "FR",
    "resourceType": "Party"
  }
]
```

Output (JSON):

```json
[
  {
    "eventType": "UPDATE",
    "eventTime": "2021-12-14T12:34:56.789012Z",
    "country": "ES",
    "resourceType": "Party"
  },
  {
    "eventType": "UPDATE",
    "eventTime": "2021-12-14T12:34:56.789012Z",
    "country": "ES",
    "resourceType": "Party"
  }
]
```